# Acceder a los tiempos ejecución de un código en tqdm

Tags: python, progressbar

Hace poco, he descubierto la librería de Python tqdm para mostrar barras de progreso en los `for` loops. A pesar de que la barra de progreso muestra el tiempo de ejecución de cada iteración del loop, me gustaría saber si esta librería guarda estos tiempos de ejecución en alguna parte, o tengo que usar `time` para ello y guardar los tiempos de ejecución en una lista. Un caso de uso sería:

```python
for i in tqdm(range(1,n+1)):
    proceso_de_duracion_aleatoria()
```

La idea es poder hacer luego un histograma o un lineplot de los tiempos de ejecución de `proceso_de_duracion_aleatoria`

Muchas gracias.

Comment: "me gustaría saber si esta librería guarda estos tiempos de ejecución en alguna parte" -> Y probaste a mirar en la [documentación de la librería](https://tqdm.github.io/)??

Comment: Tal vez guardando en un archivo el progreso, con el parámetro `file`. https://tqdm.github.io/docs/tqdm/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes acceder a esa información a través de la propiedad [`format_dict`](https://tqdm.github.io/docs/tqdm/#format_dict) de los objetos `tdqm`, la clave que buscas es `"elapsed"`:

```
from tqdm import tqdm


n = 10

with tqdm(range(1, n + 1)) as t:
    for i in t:
        ...
    elapsed_time = t.format_dict['elapsed']

print(elapsed_time)
```

También puedes usar por comodidad `trange`:

```
from tqdm import trange

...

with trange(1, n + 1) as t:
    for i in t:
        ...
    elapsed_time = t.format_dict['elapsed']
```

En este caso se guarda el tiempo final, si quieres el de cada iteración basta con obtener el valor al final de cada iteración del `for` y almacenarlo (en una lista por ejemplo):

```
from tqdm import tqdm


n = 10
times = []

with tqdm(range(1, n + 1)) as t:
    for i in t:
        ...
        times.append(t.format_dict['elapsed'])

print(times)
```

---

Téngase en cuenta que [`tqdm` internamente usa simplemente
`time.time()`](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/blob/cc372d09dcd5a5eabdc6ed4cf365bdb0be004d44/tqdm/std.py#L1077). Si se quiere medir tiempos de ejecución apropiadamente, existen mejores funciones para medir el rendimiento del código como `time.perf_counter()` o `time.process_time()` y, por supuesto, el módulo `timeit`.

Answer (score -2):

Sí, es posible acceder a los tiempos de ejecución de cada iteración del bucle utilizando tqdm. Puedes hacer esto utilizando un enfoque que involucre medir el tiempo dentro del bucle. Aquí tienes un ejemplo de cómo podrías hacerlo:

```
import time
from tqdm import tqdm

# Lista para almacenar los tiempos de ejecución
tiempos_ejecucion = []

# Bucle con tqdm
for i in tqdm(range(1, n+1)):
    inicio_proceso = time.time()  # Momento de inicio del proceso
    proceso_de_duracion_aleatoria()  # Proceso a ejecutar
    fin_proceso = time.time()  # Momento de finalización del proceso
    tiempo_ejecucion = fin_proceso - inicio_proceso  # Tiempo transcurrido durante el proceso
    tiempos_ejecucion.append(tiempo_ejecucion)  # Agregar el tiempo de ejecución a la lista

# Ahora `tiempos_ejecucion` contiene los tiempos de ejecución de cada iteración
```

Espero que esto te ayude!

Comment: Basicamente le contestaste lo que ya sabia??? "me gustaría saber si esta librería guarda estos tiempos de ejecución en alguna parte ó tengo que usar time para ello". Y tu respuesta, se contradice.. usas time, no la libreria.. entonces la respuesta es no, no podes usando la libreria, tenes que usar time....